# Ubuntu 13.04: can't connect to many sites (including github) in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: 13.04, firefox, google-chrome, github

[I have posted the same issue on Ubuntu forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145713 . I am repeating it here to see if I can find an answer here.]

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 recently, and found that I can't connect to many sites, including Github, using Firefox(21.0) and Chrome(26.0.1410.63). I can visit all these sites on Windows, in all browsers.

Firefox continues to load the site, but doesn't show any contents. Chrome gives an error after a while:

> Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Some websites are loaded partially.

Some other sites with this issue: bitbucket(works on Chrome but not in Firefox), yahoo mail, 500px (partially loaded), images served from pcdn.500px.com are not loaded.

I also can't clone (git clone) github repositories: I get "error: operation timed out". I can clone bitbucket repos.

In addition I noticed the following "SSL" issue while using "pip" to install Python packages; the packages do get installed. I am including this in here in case it is related to the above issue:

```
$ pip install ipython
Downloading/unpacking ipython
Could not fetch URL https://github.com/ipython/ipython/downloads (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/ipython/): There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: <urlopen error _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out>
Will skip URL https://github.com/ipython/ipython/downloads when looking for download links for ipython
Downloading ipython-0.13.2.tar.gz (6.0MB): 6.0MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython

Installing collected packages: ipython
Running setup.py install for ipython

Installing ipcontroller script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing iptest script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing ipcluster script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing ipython script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing pycolor script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing iplogger script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing irunner script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Installing ipengine script to /home/phn/.virtualenvs/default2.7/bin
Successfully installed ipython
Cleaning up...
```

Note that I have none of these issues in Windows.

**[Edit: May 17 2013]**

Output from running curl on github:

```
[phn@phn ~ ]
$ curl -I http://github.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 17 May 2013 03:33:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
Location: https://github.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding

[phn@phn ~ ]
$ curl -I https://github.com
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

I hope someone can help me fix this.

Thanks,

Prasanth

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @douggro I have put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bFk9R5sz

Comment: My best guess at this point is a problem with your libnss3 libraries. These support the certificate authentication for SSL and HTTPS connections amongst other things. If you have Synaptic installed, it's pretty easy to search your 'Installed' packages to see if it's installed, and re-install if necessary.

Comment: @douggro I re-installed libnss3 and libnss3-1d, both of which were already installed, but it didn't solve the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: I'd keep searching in the lines of a problem with certificate handling as a possible cause. Failure to work with HTTPS requests certainly points that direction.

Comment: @douggro I tried connecting to github/bitbucket from Live session using ISO disk, and can't connect using either Firefox or wget.

Comment: I'm downloading 13.04 now to test. The fact that it happens from a Live session moves this in another direction: the PPoE connection. Might be a driver issue with your Ethernet controller routing the SSL connections. Run `lspci` and find your networking hardware, then do a search for issues with it here on askubuntu and Google.

Comment: @douggro I just read your comment. I couldn't afford to spend any more time on this, and so I switched to 12.04 LTS a few days ago. I don't have any problems on 12.04(except that the computer gets very hot, but that is another issue!). Thanks for the help.